# jQuery Dialog Confirmation After Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for this project, and have a jQuery UI dialog box to confirm when the form is submitted. I'd like to display the dialog after the form has been successfully validated, but I'm not sure where the function needs to go.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function submitForm(response) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
        if (response.success == true) {
            $('#response').html('Your application was successfully submitted.').removeClass('hide');
            $('.confirm').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#response').html(response).removeClass('hide');
            $('.confirm').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'application.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#application').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: submitForm
            });
            return false;
        },
        showErrors: function(map, list) {
            var focused = document.activeElement;
            if (focused && $(focused).is('input, textarea')) {
                $(this.currentForm).tooltip('close', {
                    currentTarget: focused
                }, true)
            }
            this.currentElements.removeAttr('title').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            $.each(list, function(index, error) {
                $(error.element).attr('title', error.message).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            });
            if (focused && $(focused).is('input, textarea')) {
                $(this.currentForm).tooltip('open', {
                    target: focused
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#application').tooltip({
        show: false,
        hide: false
    });
    $('#application').validate({
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            phone: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                phoneUS: true
            },
            phone_alt: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                phoneUS: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            phone: {
                phoneUS: 'Please enter a valid phone number with area code.'
            },
            phone_alt: {
                phoneUS: 'Please enter a valid phone number with area code.'
            },
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        }
    });

    $('#application input:not(:submit)').addClass('ui-widget-content');
    $('button, input:submit, input:button').button();

    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Confirm': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $('.confirm').click();
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $('.confirm').click(function (e,ui) {
        if (!e.isTrigger) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Again, this works, I'd just rather the user only need to confirm once (after the form is validated). Thanks!

Edit: Now it's working as intended with the changes below.

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
}

$('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'application.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#exhibitor-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: submitForm
            });
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Refer to the docs.  Anything that needs to be done after the form is validates, goes inside of the `submitHandler` function.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler